# SQL - filtering out certain types of duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working with MySQL database with around 30,000 records and trying to come up with a query that filters out certain types of duplicate records.

There are two relevant columns - `email` and `flag`. I need to get all records that do not have a duplicate `email`. For the records that have duplicate `email`, I exclude them only if for ALL those duplicates, the `flag` is set to 'no'. If, for one of those rows, the `flag` is 'yes', then I need to return all of those records.

So far, I have this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac20d/6
It currently returns rows 3,4,5,6,7,11,12. I need it to return 3,4,5,6,7,**8,9**,11,12.

Any help shall be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Will you return the EMAIL any time at least one record has flag = 'yes'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand why you don't return 10 in the result. It follows your rules but it's an empty string. So, I've come up with this:

```
select * from mytable where email IN (
select 
email
from
mytable t
group by email
having count(email) = 1 or EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable st 
                                            WHERE t.email = st.email 
                                            AND st.flag = 'yes')
)
AND email != ''
```

Is it what you need?

**[sqlfiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac20d/28/0)**

Comment: I don't want to speak for the OP, but if the point is to do something with email addresses, it might make sense to exclude email addresses that are empty strings.

Comment: That's why I added the `and email != ''` at the end :)

Comment: I know. I was responding to your statement, *"I do not understand why you don't return 10 in the result."*

Comment: Thank you for such a fast response. This is what I was looking for. However, when running this query on a table with around 30,000 records, it takes around a minute. Would you have an idea on how to improve this? Thanks!! PS: I had forgotten to mention that I was excluding empty email addresses as well - Thanks!

Comment: Performance questions are not easy to answer. It might be better to ask this in a different question. Quick answer would be to run the query like `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to see if indexes are used. An index on email sure is a good idea.

Comment: @CheekuJee Let me know the result :)

Comment: @tombom I appreciate all your help. This is what I get from 'EXPLAIN ...'. I am not sure what this means. http://oi41.tinypic.com/zm1j6a.jpg Thanks!

Comment: You have to be strong now. This is the worst execution plan I've ever seen. ;) But, there is hope. That it only took a minute is a good thing, so bad is the execution plan. It basically says, that it's scanning the whole table and that there is no index and therefore none is used. Try `ALTER TABLE yourTableName ADD INDEX idx_indexName (email);`

Comment: @tombom Thank you so much!! Altering the table to allow indexing really helps. Now, the query runs in around 0.11 seconds. I appreciate your help and this solves my issue.